# Sorting HashMap and its nested HashMap

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I'm trying to sort nested hashMaps , where both HashMaps need to be sorted.

The first hashMap should be sorted by key. Second one should be sorted by value.
So far I manage to sort the keys of the first hashMap by making an array of the keys and sort it .

My hashmap looks like this

```
 HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>> carOwners = new 
                                    HashMap<String,HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

an Example is let say we have first String is Name , car brand, qnty.

Example:
David:

Audi>5

Bmw>4

Izabel:

VW>10

MB>4

So Basicly first we sort the names, and then we sort the nested hash by value. How can this be done ... cant find any useful information :(>

Comment: You can not sort an `HashMap`, please consider using `LinkedHashMap` instead

Comment: By nature of `HashMap` they have no ordering. What do you mean by sorting them?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen `LinkedHashMap` is a `HashMap`. And technically you can't sort a `LinkedHashMap` either.

Comment: @DavidsAmause Do you need to *maintain* the sort? That is, are you adding items to the map(s)?

Comment: @shmosel you're right. `LinkedHashMap` only maintain the sorted order. [An example of sort map](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/)

Comment: Seriosly can't sort HashMap?

It is the only way I figured out to solve my problem and it is that I read for example from a document

David > audi 
David > adui
David > bmw
david > bmw 

And so on , so I put them in nested hashMap and increment only the value of the seonc hash to count the cars.
However I need to print after that alphabetic the names + from most cars? ... no way to solve this with hash? What is the other way then?

Comment: @DavidsAmause Seriously. Why would you need to?

Comment: *"Seriossly can't sort HashMap?"* - Yes.  Seriously.  *"It is the only way I figured out to solve my problem ..."*  - well you need need to rethink your problem.  There are always alternatives.  For example, don't use `HashMap` as your only data structure.

Comment: Such as ? I'm seriosly stuck with this one ...
The whole point of the hashMap is to link key>value ...

I can easy sort hashMap , but with nested i jsut cant figure it out...

Comment: Stuck why? Have you considered `TreeMap`. It *is* sorted.

Comment: As others mentioned already, `HashSet`s have no ordering by concept. However there are many implementations of `Map` that offer management of `key-value`-pairs. For example everything that implements `SortedMap`. That is, for example, `TreeMap`. But there are many other possible sorted map data-structures, also different tree variants. They all have advantages and disadvantages. `HashMap` provides a fast direct get-access where TreeMap maintains its content sorted but therefore only having `Theta(log(n))` get-access and so on.

Answer (score 3):

For sorting a `Map` you can use the following class: `TreeMap`. As the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) says,

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

If you want to sort the elements in *insertion order*, please use [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

For sorting a `Map` by value, please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java). It's also for Java7 and Java8.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 3):

Make the first map as TreeMap and for the second Map, sort it by values. Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java)

Below is the code snippet for your problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> carOwners = new TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> nameQuantity = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    nameQuantity.put("Audi", 5);
    nameQuantity.put("BMW", 4);
    carOwners.put("David", sortByValue(nameQuantity)); 
    nameQuantity = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    nameQuantity.put("VW", 10);
    nameQuantity.put("MB", 4);
    carOwners.put("Izabel", sortByValue(nameQuantity)); 
    for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> carOwnerEntry : carOwners.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(carOwnerEntry.getKey());
        HashMap<String, Integer> nameQty = carOwnerEntry.getValue();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> nameQtyEntry : nameQty.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(nameQtyEntry.getKey() + " " + nameQtyEntry.getValue());
        }
    }

public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> HashMap<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
        });
    HashMap<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```